# MySQL TIME_DIFF expr1 and expr2 in seconds.microseconds

Tags: mysql, time, seconds

I have 2 values ​​in my table, for example:

```
value1 = 08:30:11.600000 
value2 = 08:30:10.000000
```

In fields with data type time (6), applying TIME_DIFF have resulted in:

```
00:00:01.600000
```

What is the possibility that the result is expressed as follows `1.60` (second.microseconds)

Or if the values ​​are

```
value1 = 08:31:11.600000 
value2 = 08:30:10.000000 
------------------------------
Result of **61.60**
```

I've been testing with this

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('08:30:11.600000','08:30:10.000000')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what your asking, so here is the answer:

```
mysql> SELECT CAST(TIMEDIFF('08:30:11.600000','08:30:10.000000')+0 AS DECIMAL(10,2));
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CAST(TIMEDIFF('08:30:11.600000','08:30:10.000000')+0 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                   1.60 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: this solution is feasible for equal time or less than 60 seconds, for 60 seconds longer times do not give the expected results, for example 

value1 = 08:31:11.600000 
value2 = 08:30:10.000000 
= Result of ** 61.60 **`